# Variable Forward Voltage Diode

Tags: diodes, audio

I'm attempting to create a guitar pedal using diodes to clip the audio signal and create distortion. Specifically, I'm trying to create a circuit with variable clipping by using a circuit that acts like a diode which has a variable voltage drop from around 0.7-3.5. It's also possible to use a Zener diode type circuit with a variable breakdown voltage.

I believe that the TL431 IC would serve this purpose, but the forward voltage drop is specified from 2.5-5 V, which is too high for the application. Are there any other components or circuits that perform a similar task with a lower voltage level?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The TLV431 (note the V) works down to 1.25 V. Or you could do something more custom with an op amp.

Comment: There is such transistor circuit; its figurative name is "rubber diode" or "VBE multiplier".

Answer (score 4):

[image: Passive AC clipping circuit Rev2]
This is a passive solution where you can control the clipping voltage by potentiometer.

Comment: Made a mistake: T2 must be PNP (e.g. BC557)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular diode with variable gain on the opamp. That will make the effective clipping voltage (relative to the signal voltage) variable.

Then apply more gain/attenuation as necessary.

Oh wait, that's what they all do anyway...